# Can't get rid of message When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import the individual SDK components you intend to use

Tags: firebase

I'm trying to use Firebase in my web project, and I can't understand how it works. I do:

```
import app from "firebase/app"; //1
import firebase from 'firebase'; //2
console.log(app === firebase);  //3
```

it outputs true.
If I use 2 string my code to get data from firebase works and I get message about not using proper SDK in production
If I use 1 string I get an error from:

```
app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = app.firestore();
```

> Uncaught TypeError:
>   firebase_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.firestore is not a
>   function

Please help me to sort out how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it, webpack is in charge. It wraps imported modules, that's why they are equal. Though, don't know how to optimize my module loads using webpack and firebase simultaneously.